# не отображается содержимое ng-template

Tags: angular

Как правильно обернуть expension-panel в ng-template в моем случае? `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'details' of undefined`. Возможно, стоит добавить в контекст `item.details`, но в таком случае ошибка не исчезает. Если не использовать ng-container и ng-template, то `details` определяется и все работает как нужно. 
Используется 4 версия ангуляра и angular-material версия 2 (знаю, что уже вышла 8 версия, но нет возможности обновиться до более новой).

```html
<md-tab-group [selectedIndex]="index" (selectedIndexChange)="index = $event">
 <md-tab label="First">
    <md-list>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tabContent; context: index">
        <md-accordion>
          <div *ngFor="let item of items">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemList; context: item"></ng-container>
          </div>
        </md-accordion>
    </md-list>
 </md-tab>
 <md-tab label="Second">...</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
<ng-template #tabContent let-index>Header</ng-template>

<ng-template #itemList let-item>
  <md-expansion-panel>
     <md-expansion-panel-header></md-expansion-panel-header>
     <div class="item-detail">
       <div *ngFor="let detail of item.details">...</div>
     </div>
  </md-expansion-panel>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: `*ngTemplateOutlet="tabContent; context: { $implicit: index }"` для таба и `*ngTemplateOutlet="itemList; context: { $implicit: item }"`

Comment: @overthesanity,  почти работает как нужно, только на всех табах, кроме первого expension-panel раскрыта, хотя индикатор панели (`mat-expansion-indicator`) показывает, что она закрыта